# ls output not compact anymore

Tags: command-line, ls

I wanted to ask about the `ls` command in lubuntu 15.10. Now there is a new line for every entry. I know from other distributions that there is also an output style where `ls` outputs the content of folders without new lines in a compact way when typed without any options. Is that possible in lubuntu, too?

Edit:

The ls version is 8.23 and `type ls` outputs

```
ls is aliased to `ls --color=auto'
```

The `-C` flag does not create a different output than without any options.

I have read the manual `man ls` after the comment, but could not find anything relevant to my question there.

Comment: `ls` is part of `coreutils` and these should be the same all across. What kind of version you have? type in `ls --version` , let us know. Also , `type ls` output would be nice to know.  `ls` also has `-C` flag, but that should be default in terminal - you wouldn't need that unless you are redirecting output to a file.

Comment: Reading `man ls` is a good first step.

Comment: @waltinator man page for ls isn't very descriptive, `info ls` is a bit more in detail, which is the source of my knowledge about `-C` and `-1` flags. OP's output suggests that he has `ls -1` behavior , while `ls -C` should be the default.

Comment: Are there any files with unusually long names in the directory you are trying to list? That can prevent it from columnising the output.

Comment: @steeldriver: YES, exactly that! After I deleted the file, the output was normal again. Thanks!!

Comment: @steeldriver good catch ! post an answer

Answer (score 2):

Very long file names will force the output of `ls` to be one per line. You could rename the file to have a shorter file name.

Or you could try the below command which forcefully truncates file names (from [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/112341) on Unix & Linux):

```
ls | cut -c1-20 | column -c"${COLUMNS:-80}"
```

If you wanted you could make a special alias to execute this with `lc`, for example, by adding the following to your `~/.bash_alisaes` file:

```
alias lc='ls | cut -c1-20 | column -c"${COLUMNS:-80}"'
```

However that alias won't allow you to pass flags like `-l` or `-a`, so instead you could make a script `~/bin/lc` and make it executable with `chmod +x ~/bin/lc`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ls $@ | cut -c1-20 | column -c"${COLUMNS:-80}"
```

Kudos @steeldriver for discovering the issue in the comments above.